# Taylor's formula for optimization for numerical method

Tags: calculus, optimization, numerical-methods

$$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+tp)^Tp$$  I'm trying to prove thıs equation proof but I can't. can someone help?

Comment: Just look up any calculus textbook... This is Lagrange's theorem for multivariable functions.\

Answer (score 1):

$g(s)=f(x+sp)$ is a scalar function. You are trying to prove
$$
g(1)=g(0)+g'(t)·(1-0)
$$
for some $t\in(0,1)$, which is the mean-value theorem. Check that the derivative is compatible with your expression. Note that while the derivative/Jacobian is a row vector, the gradient is a column vector. In the usual Euclidean context it is the transpose of the Jacobian matrix.